# Special date conversion

Tags: oracle, date, oracle10g, type-conversion

My question is simple:

- I have a date in oracle the format is : **07.08.13**.
- I want to have : **8/2013**.

I used

```
TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM/YYYY');
```

- The result is : **08/2013**.

The problem is the zero, is there any conversion solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get rid of leading zeros use `FM` format model modifier:

```
SQL> select TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'fmMM/YYYY')
  2    from dual
  3  ;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'FMMM/YYYY')
----------------------------
8/2013
```

Answer (score 2):

Certainly in PostgreSQL you can add FM before the MM to remove any leading 0's:

Running:

```
select to_char(now(), 'yyyy/mm/dd');
```

Produces:

```
2013/08/07
```

Whereas running:

```
select to_char(now(), 'yyyy/FMmm/dd');
```

Produces:

```
2013/8/07
```

And according to this the same should work in oracle.:
http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php

So I would try:

```
TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'FMMM/YYYY');
```

HTH